# Fail docker container after cpu limit

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, devops, docker-swarm

I am running a java process as a docker swarm service. But that service is hogging my CPU, eventually. I tried with CPU limit as 1, and docker stats showing that container to be consistent 100%, but I want to fail that container in 95% and recreated. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, you need to restart the container if the CPU is higher than 95%?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yeah, precisely.

Answer (score 4):

CPU is a compressible resource, unlike memory. When memory requests exceed the limit, the kernel will kill the app. When CPU exceeds the limit, the kernel simply gives that process less time on the CPU and it runs slower.

There's no built in capability to change this behavior. You would need to implement some form of external monitoring with the ability to kill the container when a threshold is exceeded.

More than likely, what you actually want is to setup a healthcheck for your container that detects the application becoming unresponsive. You will need to run the container using swarm mode to automatically recreate the container with the failing healthcheck.